# Bootstrap 5.3 Change Backdrop To Static on Open Modal (JavaScript/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

How can I change a backdrop to 'static' on an open modal via jQuery or JavaScript? ? I need to prevent the user from closing the modal on click after they click the 'Submit' button on the modal. I tried all the following but I can't get it working. Thanks!

```
$('.modal').attr('data-bs-backdrop','static');
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal');
$('.modal').attr('data-bs-backdrop="static"');
$("#myModal").modal({'data-bs-backdrop': "static"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Those HTML `data-*` attributes need to be added to the HTML before bootstrap initializes the page.  You cannot add them afterwards to "update" the modal options.

A boostrap modal can be "created" in one of two different ways.

- [via data attributes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#via-data-attributes)
- [via JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#via-javascript)

To make your modal static you need to either add the `data` attributes directly to the HTML, or change the JavaScript related to how the modal is created.